# How to achieve a responsive ribbon shape in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image]

Trying to achieve this with css.
I've achieved in doing this but this breaks if my label (CAREER) is longer the size of the `div`. If its longer then the content wraps and the height of the `div` increases. But the left ribbon cut does not do that responsively. Can someone suggest a better approach?

```css
.custom-tag-container {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  border-color: green green green transparent;
  padding: 4px !important;
}

.custom-tag-container>p {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex: 1;
  margin: auto;
}

#triangle-left {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: transparent;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateX(-12.5px) translateY(12.5px);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: green green transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-tag-container">
  <div id="triangle-left" />
  <p>Hello Worldsm</p>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sabirahmed/yvz7jneL/30/)

Comment: Check out this article https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

Comment: Is your ribbon background transparent or has white background?

Comment: @Justinas: Transparent in this case, but ideally can be a different color too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an idea that rely on skew transformation where it will be responsive and you will have transparency:

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
  position:relative;
  margin:5px;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  height:50%;
  width:3px;
  background:green;
}
.box:before {
  top:0;
  transform:skew(45deg);
  transform-origin:top;
}
.box:after {
  bottom:0;
  transform:skew(-45deg);
  transform-origin:bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="height:80px"></div>
```

[image: Ribbon Edge CSS]

If you want to keep the same width for the arrow, you can consider a different idea using background:

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
  position:relative;
  margin:5px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  height:50%;
  width:30px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top right,
      transparent calc(50% - 4px),green,transparent 50%) 
      bottom/100% calc(100% + 4px);
}
.box:after {
  transform:scaleY(-1);
  transform-origin:bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="height:80px"></div>
```

and with SVG too

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
  position:relative;
  margin:5px;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  height:50%;
  width:30px;
  background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 15 15" preserveAspectRatio="none"><line x1="0" y1="-1" x2="15" y2="16" stroke="green"  /></svg>') 0 0/100% 100%;
}
.box:after {
  transform:scaleY(-1);
  transform-origin:bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="height:80px"></div>
```

[image]

You can also optimize the code and do it without pseudo element:

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
  margin:5px;
  background:
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 15 15" preserveAspectRatio="none"><line x1="0" y1="-1" x2="15" y2="16" stroke="green"  /></svg>') top left/30px 50%,
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 15 15" preserveAspectRatio="none"><line x1="0" y1="16" x2="15" y2="-1" stroke="green"  /></svg>') bottom left/30px 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="height:80px"></div>
```

The same SVG can be used to obtain the first result where the arrow width is also dynamic. The trick is to only define the height and preserve the ratio:

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
  margin:5px;
  background:
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 15 15"><line x1="0" y1="-1" x2="15" y2="16" stroke="green"  /></svg>') top left/auto 50%,
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 15 15"><line x1="0" y1="16" x2="15" y2="-1" stroke="green"  /></svg>') bottom left/auto 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="height:80px"></div>
```

---

You can easily add a coloration inside too.

With skew transformation:

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:0;
  margin:5px;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:50%;
  border-left:3px solid green;
  background:yellow;
}
.box:before {
  top:0;
  transform:skew(45deg);
  transform-origin:top;
}
.box:after {
  bottom:0;
  transform:skew(-45deg);
  transform-origin:bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="height:80px"></div>
```

With the SVG background

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  padding-left:30px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
  margin:5px;
  background:
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 15 15" preserveAspectRatio="none"><polygon points="16,17 16,-2 0,-1 " fill="yellow" stroke="green" /></svg>') top left/30px 50%,
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 15 15" preserveAspectRatio="none"><polygon points="16,16 16,-2 0,16 " fill="yellow" stroke="green" /></svg>') bottom left/30px 50%,
   yellow content-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="height:80px"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help. But I'm still stuck. Here you're specifying the height in the style. Is there a way it calculates the size of the div automatically and resizes the height dynamically. This is cause I don't have info about the size of the label that will be present. Edit: Got it fixed just changed the property height to min-height.
Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @AbsoluteSith I am specifying *different* heights to highlight the responsive. No need to add height, simply put your content inside and it will adjust automatically

Answer (score 1):

If you have white-on-white background, then you can use two *css-triangles* that one covers other and creates edge for ribbon. If you need some transparency, then you should rely on [`clip-path`](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2018/11/29/an-introduction-to-css-shapes/) *(check if support is proper for your users)* **OR** some SVG elements.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ribbon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 120px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.ribbon:before,
.ribbon:after {
  content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 100px solid green;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  
  .ribbon:after {
  border-left-color: white;
  left: -3px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="ribbon">CARRIER</div>
```

---

For less-hacky approach use simple background image.